# how to use pip3 to install panda

Tags: apt, python

I have python both python2.7.12 and python 3.5.2 on my Ubuntu 16.04

I'm trying to install panda as bellow:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ pip3 install pandas
```

And I got this message:

```
"Collecting pandas
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

I had also the same error message using this command `sudo -H pip3 install pandas`.

Comment: by what miracle did you get both python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 installed on ubuntu? I'd like a guide on how to do this. how do installing apps know which python to use?

Comment: i installed both of them using sudo apt-get install                                          then sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip to install the pip

Answer (score 2):

You can install pandas in ubuntu using `apt`, for python3 you should run:

```
sudo apt install python3-pandas
```

---

Also you can try updating `pip3` before trying to install pandas.

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user pip3
pip3 install pandas --user
```

it might works.

Comment: thanks you  but even while updating *pip3* i got the same error                                 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip3

Comment: So I suggest you to use `python3-pandas` from official repositories... that would be the best choice I guess.

Comment: this may be a solution but actually i need to use the **pip** for installing other packages  like                                                                                                        **sudo pip install MACS2 **                                                                                                  **pip3 install rpy2**                                                                                                                       because im getting the same error everytime i use **pip** and i dont understand why